# generic way to get a value from different objects without a common super type

Tags: java, generics

I am using an open API (so can't change the code on their side), which provide an array of enum value types.

```
User.IDType.values();
```

Problem is for each type in above array. I have to call a value() function to return an array of String values for supplied types.

```
public static String[] enumValues(IDType[] types) {
        String[] values = new String[types.length];
        for ( int i=0; i < types.length; i++ ) {
            values[i] = types[i].value();
        }

        return values;
    }
```

In order to avoid writing this function for each type I want to write a generic method like below but the problem is: How to call the function value for a generic type?

```
static <T> String[] enumValues(T[] types)
    {
        String[] values = new String[types.length];
        for (int i=0; i<types.length; i++) {
            values[i] = types[i].value;
        }

        return values;
    }
```

> NOTE: Any of the types doesn't have a superclass ex: Type, which I can
>   use.

Comment: Take a look at [Class.getMethod()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))

Answer (score 0):

In general, you upper bound the type variable when you declare it:

```
<T extends SomeType>
```

Then you can invoke methods/access fields from `SomeType` in references of type T in the method body.

However, generics get you nothing for this method. Arrays are covariant, so you can pass why array with element type as a subtype of `IDType`.

Don't mix generics and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have following restriction:

> Any of the types doesn't have a superclass ex: Type, which I can use.

The remaining solution is to use reflection API.
However, such solution is **not type safe**, **runtime error**, instead of **compile time error** will throw when the `value` method is changed in the Enum. Following is an example using reflection API.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GenericEnumTest {
    static <T> String[] enumValues(T[] types) {
        String[] values = new String[types.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            Method valueMethod;
            try {
                valueMethod = types[i].getClass().getMethod("value");
                values[i] = (String) valueMethod.invoke(types[i]);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException
                    | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] result = enumValues(new IDType[] { IDType.TEST1, IDType.TEST2 });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static enum IDType {
        TEST1("test1"), TEST2("test2");

        private IDType(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        private String value;

        public String value() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference :[Java Doc Class.getMethod()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-)
[Java Doc Method class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Function<T, String>` as a mapper to extract the `String` value from an enum value instance. This mapper function would be passed to `enumValues` as follows:

```
   public static <T> String[] enumValues(T[] types, Function<T, String> mapper) {
        String[] values = new String[types.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            values[i] = mapper.apply(types[i]);
        }

        return values;
    }
```

The usage is simple:

```
String[] ids = enumValues(User.IDType.values(), t -> t.value);
```

This works because the type of `T` of the mapper function is infered from the [component type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayComponents.html) of the provided enum value array. Thus the `t` is an enum value instance and we can use every visible member of `t` - in this case `value`.

As long as every enum value has a public field `value` you can use  `t -> t.value`. If you would use a method `value()` instead of the field `value` you could write `t -> t.value()` which would be equivalent to `User.IDType::value`. This shows explicit the mapper function depends on the type `T`. Thus if an enum value type doesn't provide a public field `value`, the mapping `t -> t.value` will result in a compile time error. This means this approach is type safe.

EDIT
Using the Stream-API you can rewrite `enumValues` as follows:

```
public static <T> String[] enumValues(T[] types, Function<T, String> mapper) {
    return Arrays.stream(types).map(mapper).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```